# Design a database schema to save some product configuration in database

Tags: mysql, postgresql

Design a database schema to save some product configuration in database. That configuration can be changed by the admin on three level.
1. Enterprise level
2. Group level
3. individual product levels

Enterprise level configuration applied on all products.
on group level configuration applied on all members of that group.

**IMPORTANT** :Group level configuration overrides enterprise level configuration and individual product level configuration overrides group level configuration.

I also have different type configuration tables that must be map with that products.

Comment: This looks like a Home Work assigment. I Vote to close it. too broad.

Comment: It is too much imperative to be a question. This is a task assignment where no effort to do something was attempted. I vote to close it.